# Control restriction of text width on responsive template

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, width

I am already using the responsive meta tag on my site which works for the most part:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

I seem to be getting problems with my "messages" page when displaying messages. Small messages seem to show with no problems, and when on the computer, large messages show fine too. Although on my phone, the large messages will go too far right and off screen so you have to scroll right off the page to read the messages.

Here is my script:

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="assets/img/defaultuser.png" alt="user" width="64px" height="64px" hspace="10px" class="media-object" align="left">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <div style="display:inline"><b><a href=""><? echo ''.$me_first_name.' '.$me_last_name.''; ?></a></b></div> <div align="right" style="float:right; display:inline"> <? echo $me_time; ?> </div><br>
    <? echo $me_message; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried messing around with the width attribute but no luck:

```
style="width:300px"
```

And have attempted to use the responsive bootstrap attributes:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
```

But this is still not keeping the text in a set block on the mobile phone browser. Is there a way I can limit the text width on the mobile phone browser only without affecting it on the PC browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you attempted to use the auto function -

```
<style>
div {
    width: auto;
    height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
</style>
```

Simply add this to your CSS code and it should automatically set the width according to the size of the display or device.

Comment: I've changed the `float: right;` to `float: left` and it seems to be working okay. I will test it a couple more times just to be sure! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I'll edit the answer as I wasn't sure which direction you aimed for.